# Parent/Child Categories Permalinks

Tags: permalinks

I have a lot of categories in my blog and I'd like the url of the archive for Child Categories to be:

***mydomain.com/child-category/***

instead of

***mydomain.com/parent-category/child-category/***

How do I can obtain this risult?

Comment: Check [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49163607/how-to-echo-parent-name-and-permalink-of-custom-taxonomy-category-on-subcategory)

Comment: Not sure is the same argument